# Color Plot by order of points in list - Mathematica

Tags: plot, wolfram-mathematica

I've got a list of three dimensional points, ordered by time.  Is there a way to plot the points so that I can get a visual representation that also includes information on where in the list the point occurred? My initial thought is to find a way to color the points by the order in which they were plotted.

`ListPlot3D` drapes a sheet over the points, with no regard to the order which they were plotted.

`ListPointPlot` just shows the points, but gives no indication as to the order in which they were plotted. It's here that I am thinking of coloring the points according to the order in which they appear in the list.

`ListLinePlot` doesn't seem to have a 3D cousin, unlike a lot of the other plotting functions.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could also do something like

```
lst = RandomReal[{0, 3}, {20, 3}];
Graphics3D[{Thickness[0.005], 
  Line[lst, 
   VertexColors -> 
    Table[ColorData["BlueGreenYellow"][i], {i, 
      Rescale[Range[Length[lst]]]}]]}]
```

[image: line with gradient]

Comment: so I was right that there was a simpler way... I'm honoured to push you over 1000 reputation points then :)

Comment: Everyone had great suggestions; it's nice that Mathematica provides so many ways to accomplish this, but you sir (or madame) receive the green check because of the simplicity of your solution.

Answer (score 5):

As you did not provide examples, I made up some by creating a 3d self-avoiding random walk:

```
Clear[saRW3d]
saRW3d[steps_]:=
    Module[{visited},
        visited[_]=False;
        NestList[
            (Function[{randMove},
                If[
                    visited[#+randMove]==False,
                    visited[#+randMove]=True;
                    #+randMove,
                    #
                ]
            ][RandomChoice[{{1,0,0},{-1,0,0},{0,1,0},{0,-1,0},{0,0,1},{0,0,-1}}]])&,
            {0,0,0},
            steps
        ]//DeleteDuplicates
]
```

(this is sort of buggy but does the job; it produces a random walk in 3d which avoids itself, ie, avoids revisiting the same place in subsequent steps).

Then we produce 100000 steps like this

```
dat = saRW3d[100000];
```

this is like I understood your data points to be. We then make these change color depepnding on which step it is:

```
datpairs = Partition[dat, 2, 1];
len = Length@datpairs;
dressPoints[pts_, lspec_] := {RGBColor[(N@First@lspec)/len, 0, 0], 
   Line@pts};
datplt = MapIndexed[dressPoints, datpairs];
```

This can also be done all at once like the other answers

```
datplt=MapIndexed[
    {RGBColor[(N@First@#2)/Length@dat, 0, 0], Line@#1} &,
    Partition[dat, 2, 1]
]
```

but I tend to avoid this sort of constructions because I find them harder to read and modify.

Finally plot the result:

```
Graphics3D[datplt]
```

[image]

The path gets redder as time advances.

If this is the sort of thing you're after, I can elaborate.

EDIT: There might well be easier ways to do this...

EDIT2: Show a large set of points to demonstrate that this is very useful to see the qualitative trend in time in cases where [arrows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7127729/color-plot-by-order-of-points-in-list-mathematica/7127952#7127952) won't scale easily.

EDIT3: Added the one-liner version.

Answer (score 5):

I think Heike's method is best, but she made it overly complex, IMHO.  I would use:

```
Graphics3D[{
  Thickness[0.005], 
  Line[lst, 
   VertexColors -> 
    ColorData["SolarColors"] /@ Rescale@Range@Length@lst ]
}]
```

[image]

(acl's data)

Comment: You're right Mr. Wizard, this way is a lot more elegant (and it's she, by the way).

Comment: @Heike - duly noted.  That I might assuage my ignorance, should I have been able to deduce that from your name/nickname?

Comment: You weren't to know. Heike is actually my given name but it's not very common (at least not where I'm from) and is used for both boys and girls.

Comment: @Heike Okay. I feel less foolish now.  How is it pronounced?

Comment: Wizard: written in the [International Phonetic Alphabet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dutch_phonology) it would be something like ɦɛikə.

Answer (score 2):

```
Graphics3D@(Arrow /@ Partition[RandomInteger[{0, 10}, {10, 3}], 2, 1])
```

[image]

Comment: That is the obvious approach; the problem with this sort of thing is that it doesn't scale. Try it with 10000 points, for instance. Anyway, +1

Answer (score 2):

As to your last question: If you want to have a kind of `ListLinePlot3D` instead of a `ListPointPlot` you could simply do the following:

```
pointList = 
  Table[{t, Sin[t] + 5 Sin[t/10], Cos[t] + 5 Cos[t/10], 
    t + Cos[t/10]}, {t, 0, 100, .5}];

ListPointPlot3D[pointList[[All, {2, 3, 4}]]] /. Point -> Line
```

[image]

Of course, in this way you can't set line properties so you have to change the rule a bit if you want that:

```
ListPointPlot3D[pointList[[All, {2, 3, 4}]]] /. 
       Point[a___] :> {Red, Thickness[0.02], Line[a]}
```

[image]

or with

```
ListPointPlot3D[pointList[[All, {2, 3, 4}]]] /. 
 Point[a___] :> {Red, Thickness[0.002], Line[a], Black, Point[a]}
```

[image]

But then, why don't you use just Graphics3D and a few graphics primitives?

Comment: BTW I used a 4D array because it was my original understanding time was to be used for coloring. On closer reading of the question this may not be the case. So, pointList[[All, {2, 3, 4}]] can be written as pointList for a list with 3D coords.