# Find the largest rectangular block satisfying some condition without iterating explicitly

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have a few large 2D arrays like:

```
   1   2  3  4  5
   --------------
1 | 0  1  1  1  0
2 | 0  1  1  1  0
3 | 0  1  0  1  1
4 | 0  1  0  1  1
```

So, the largest rectangular block (by area) satisfying `==1`  starts at (1,2) and its dimensions are (2,3).

How to find it with Mathematica without iterating explicitly?

---

NB:

Just to ease your testing here is one of my samples:

```
matrix = ImageData@Binarize@Import@"https://i.stack.imgur.com/ux7tA.png"
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is a simple problem.  What happens if multiple ranges meet your condition?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Largest_empty_rectangle

Comment: Had this problem in a programming contest I was at a while ago :P

Comment: Had almost the same question myself a few days ago...

Comment: @rcollyer In my particular case, any of them will do ...

Comment: @jli I am trying to do some image segmentation ... just one of the applications cited in the article :)

Comment: My friend came up with an O(n lg n) solution but I can't remember what it is..

Comment: Er that was for a square, the rectangle one is O(n^2) worst case.

Comment: @jli Currently I am more interested in Mathematica programming style than in efficiency. I want to get it done without loops :)

Comment: You're aware that your downloadable example contains reals that are not all  either 0 or 1?

Comment: @Sjoerd It was a binary image when I uploaded it. Perhaps the image storage service compressed it and changed that. Please `Binarize[]`and disregard any real (gray) pixel.

Comment: @Sjoerd Added `Binarize` to my "code". Thanks for the warning!

Comment: What does mean 'largest'? The largest perimeter or area?

Comment: @Nakilon Area. This word is only 3 words removed from the word "largest" in the question...

Comment: If we could assume that the component regions were delimited by convex polygons, we could try computing the largest orthogonal rectangle (http://cgm.cs.mcgill.ca/~athens/cs507/Projects/2003/DanielSud/), but this alone seems fairly challenging.

Comment: @David I tried, but could not find a good reason for the convex hypothesis, sorry :(

Comment: @belisarius Neither can I. But I thought that would be a simpler condition which, if solved, would perhaps inspire a more general approach.

Comment: @David perhaps calculating the convex hull of the `ColorNegate` matrix could approximate the result somewhat. But the resulting rectangle will be always smaller than the maximum one.

Comment: @belisarius I don't follow your reasoning. How does a negative of the image help?

Comment: @David It was just a ranting. If I restrict the "white" space to the convex hull of the complement, any rectangle in there will be ok. That is not needed now with a lot of good answers already here.

Comment: A more complex version of this question can be found here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7332065/what-is-the-best-algorithm-to-find-the-largest-black-convex-area-in-an-image/7333576#7333576). It might be fun trying to solve that one with mma as well.

Comment: @Sjoerd That one is nice AND difficult. Good find!

Comment: @belisarius I haven't got a clue as to how to tackle that one. It might need a complete new approach. Any ideas?

Comment: @Sjoerd I have a nice O(n!) approach :)

Comment: @belisarius n=number of pixels = 10 000 000? Sounds like it should work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is my attempt using `BitAnd`

```
maxBlock[mat_] := Block[{table, maxSeq, pos},

  maxSeq[list_] := 
   Max[Length[#] & /@ Append[Cases[Split[list], {1 ..}], {}]];

  table = 
   Flatten[Table[
     MapIndexed[{#2[[1]], maxSeq[#1]} &, 
      FoldList[BitAnd[#1, #2] &, mat[[k]], Drop[mat, k]]], {k, 1, 
      Length[mat]}], 1];

  pos = Ordering[(Times @@@ table), -1][[1]];

  {Times[##], {##}} & @@ table[[pos]]]
```

Result for belisarius' picture:

```
Timing[maxBlock[Unitize[matrix, 1.]]]

(* {1.13253, {23433, {219, 107}}} *)
```

On the plus side this code seems faster than David's and Sjoerd's code, but for some reason it returns a rectangle which is one smaller in both dimensions than their result. Since the difference is exactly one I suspect a counting error somewhere but I can't find it at the moment.

Comment: +1, very nice. in any case the tiny bug is easy to squash: add 1 to the results :)

Comment: WoW ... That is fast! Very nice!

Comment: strange, I get 220, 108 when I try your code, which seems to be the correct answer.

Comment: I see where I went wrong. I tried my code on `matrix = ImageData@Import@"http://i.stack.imgur.com/ux7tA.png"` (without `Binarize`, which is why I used `Unitize`). With `Binarize` I get 220, 108 as well.

Comment: BTW very nice code. It took a bit of mind jogging before I could grasp it and I was satisfied it would indeed find the largest rectangle in special cases with several holes. I had been thinking on this 'sweeping action' you do (using Times in my case) but couldn't find a nice functional way to do it. The `MapIndexed` / `FoldList` combo is a nice one. I still wonder whether it can't be improved, because a lot of BitAnding is done again and again.

Answer (score 5):

Well, just to prove it's possible using functional programming here's my terribly, terribly inefficient brute force approach:

First, I generate a list of all possible squares, sorted in order of descending area:

```
rectangles = Flatten[
               Table[{i j, i, j}, 
                     {i, Length[matrix]}, 
                     {j, Length[matrix[[1]]]}
               ],1 
             ] // Sort // Reverse;
```

For a given rectangle I do a `ListCorrelate`. If a free rectangle of this size can be found in the matrix there should be at least one number in the result that corresponds to the area of that rectangle (assuming the matrix contains only 1's and 0's). We check that using `Max`. As long as we don't find a match we look for smaller rectangles (`LengthWhile` takes care of that). We end up with the largest rectangle number that fits in the matrix:

```
LengthWhile[
   rectangles, 
   Max[ListCorrelate[ConstantArray[1, {#[[2]], #[[3]]}], matrix]] != #[[1]] &
]
```

On my laptop, using belisarius' image, it took 156 seconds to find that the 11774+1th rectangle (+1 because the `LengthWhile` returns the number of the last rectangle that doesn't fit) is the largest one that will fit

```
In[70]:= rectangles[[11774 + 1]]

Out[70]= {23760, 220, 108}
```

Comment: that does work. it would be interesting to know if there is any simple algorithm with much better complexity than this.

Comment: @Sjoerd +1 Well done! I will accept if nobody comes up with something more efficient.

Comment: @acl The wikipedia lemma cited above mentions some algorithms, but I bet they use iteration...   I actually first thought of using one of V8's new image processing functions, but couldn't find a useful one (in this context) on short notice so I defaulted on this one.

Comment: You can set an upper bound on the area of the rectangles to try as: `uBound = Total@Flatten@matrix;rect = DeleteCases[rectangles, x_ /; x[[1]] > uBound];`

Comment: @yoda Yep, makes it go down to 59 s. I suppose there are more quick wins to be found this way, for instance, looking for the longest vertical and horizontal line. Area can't be higher than the product of their lengths.

Answer (score 4):

A viable option is to ignore the dictum to avoid iteration.

First a routine to find the largest length given a fixed width. Use it on the transposed matrix to reverse those dimensions. It works by divide and conquer, so is reasonably fast.

```
maxLength[mat_, width_, min_, max_] := Module[
  {len = Floor[(min + max)/2], top = max, bottom = min, conv},
  While[bottom <= len <= top,
   conv = ListConvolve[ConstantArray[1, {len, width}], mat];
   If[Length[Position[conv, len*width]] >= 1,
    bottom = len;
    len = Ceiling[(len + top)/2],
    top = len;
    len = Floor[(len + bottom)/2]];
   If[len == bottom || len == top, Return[bottom]]
   ];
  bottom
  ]
```

Here is the slower sweep code. We find the maximal dimensions and for one of them we sweep downward, maximizing the other dimension, until we know we cannot improve on the maximal area. The only efficiency I came up with was to increase the lower bounds based on prior lower bounds, so as to make the maxLength calls slightly faster.

```
maxRectangle[mat_] := Module[
  {min, dims = Dimensions[mat], tmat = Transpose[mat], maxl, maxw, 
   len, wid, best},
  maxl = Max[Map[Length, Cases[Map[Split, mat], {1 ..}, 2]]];
  maxw = Max[Map[Length, Cases[Map[Split, tmat], {1 ..}, 2]]];
  len = maxLength[tmat, maxw, 1, maxl];
  best = {len, maxw};
  min = maxw*len;
  wid = maxw - 1;
  While[wid*maxl >= min,
   len = maxLength[tmat, wid, len, maxl];
   If[len*wid > min, best = {len, wid}; min = len*wid];
   wid--;
   ];
  {min, best}
  ]
```

This is better than Sjoerd's by an order of magnitude, being only terrible and not terrible^2.

```
In[364]:= Timing[maxRectangle[matrix]]

Out[364]= {11.8, {23760, {108, 220}}}
```

Daniel Lichtblau

Answer (score 1):

I cannot compete with Heike's logic, but I can refactor her code a little.

```
maxBlock[mat_] := Module[{table, maxSeq, pos, i},
  maxSeq = Max[0, Length /@ Split@# ~Cases~ {1 ..}] &;
  table = Join @@
    Table[
       {i++, maxSeq@j},
       {k, Length@mat},
       {j, i = 1; FoldList[BitAnd, mat[[k]], mat~Drop~k]}
    ];
  pos = Ordering[Times @@@ table, -1][[1]];
  {# #2, {##}} & @@ table[[pos]]
]
```

I believe this is cleaner, and it runs about 20% faster.

Comment: @belisarius thanks.  I took a break from StackOverflow for a couple of months while I did other things.

Comment: Not sure whether you should refer to Heike as 'her'. It is a male name in some parts of my country, see http://www.nobelprize.org/nobel_prizes/physics/laureates/1913/onnes-bio.html

Comment: @Sjoerd Try as I may, try as I might... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7127729/color-plot-by-order-of-points-in-list-mathematica/7128218#7128218 (comments) ;-)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I have missed something. Why do you consider the usage of `Block` in this case as an abuse of `Block`?

Comment: @Alexey I make the edit to follow up on [this comment](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31449/map-function-on-the-specified-location/31453#comment98165_31453), which has an example.  In this particular case it shouldn't matter if `mat` is numeric but still it is not "good practice" IMHO.

Answer (score -2):

Do you consider convolution as iterating explicitly? If not then it can be used to do what you want. With a simple kernel, say 3x3 1s, you can quickly zero out those non-contiguous 1s.

Edit:

Mathematica has built-in convolution function, you can use that, or brew your own:

Here's the pseudo code (untested of course :)

```
kernel = [ [1,1,1], [1,1,1], [1,1,1] ]

for row = 1, row <= image_height - 1, row++
  for col = 1, col <= image_width - 1, col++
    compare kernel with the 3x3 matrix at image(row, col):
      if there is 0 on left AND right of the center column, OR
      if there is 0 on top AND bottom of center row, THEN
         zero out whole area from image(row-1, col-1) to image(row+1, col+1)
         # The above may need refinement
  end
end
```

After that what's left are the contiguous square area of 1s. You can do connected area analysis and determine the biggest area from there.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but it doesn't really meet the OP's requirement "How to find it with Mathematica without iterating explicitly?"

Comment: My limited experience tells me that that's not possible. Sounds like doing search without searching.

Comment: In the functional programming style you can hide a lot of implicit iterations

Comment: @holygeek: I think that belisarius wants to use Mathematica's pattern matching (or some functional or recursive approach) to do the search without being explicit about the underlying steps/loops.

Comment: @holygeek I guess what belisarius wants is something similar in spirit to this: To obtain all sequences in a list that contain more than 1 consecutive elements, one can do `Select[Split[lst], Length@# > 1 &]`. Clearly something somewhere is iterating, but you don't explicitly specify it in your code.